# How to you quick toggle cell Notes in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel

I work with excel files that use a lot of "Notes".

I know I can right-click on a cell to toggle note visibility, and I also know the shortcut <kbd>ALT+R+T+O</kbd>. However these are cumbersome when I look to toggle notes constantly.

I've added a macro, on <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> that reads:

```
Sub ToggleNote()
'
' ToggleNote Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Q
'
    ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = Not ActiveCell.Comment.Visible
End Sub
```

But there are a few limitations with this:

1. I receive a new excel every day (by email) and It's cumbersome to convert it to .xlsm & add the macro.
2. Some of the tool we use in the company blocks `.xlsm` files making them hard to share.
3. The macro is a little glitchy if I accidentally use it on a cell with no comment.

Is there a good way to do this that I'm not aware of?

PS. The excel files are written using Python & XlsxWriter - it is feasible to modify the code that creates the excels.

Comment: In the Review menu you can toggle comments on & off for the whole workbook. Does this not do what you want?

Comment: Does your macro test for a comment before trying to execute?

Comment: Hi @Absinthe - no, the workbook has 1k+ comments. It's better to do it on a cell by cell basis.

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy commands for this:

```
' Show all comments/notes
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
' Hide all comments/notes (but show the indicator)
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
```

There also is:

```
' Hide all comments/notes, even the indicator:
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlNoIndicator
```

But this makes it difficult to see which cells have comments/notes and which not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Add In which would have the macro enable for each use of Excel.  You can modify this to just happen with certain workbooks etc.

In the workbook_open of the Addin you could have

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^q","mdlFunctions.DisplayNotes"
End Sub
```

Then in a module called mdlFunctions in the AddIn, have your toggling code, mine's `DisplayNotes()`.  You may want to check for a comment being present within that code too.

You can just have this add in installed, then workboks won't become macro enabled, but you will have the macro function from the addin.

Answer (score 0):

> The excel files are written using Python & XlsxWriter - it is feasible to modify the code that creates the excels.

Yes. [It is possible in XlsxWriter to generate the notes/comments](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_comments.html) as initially visible or hidden, either individually or for all comments in a worksheet. See

Comment: Not sure you understood my question. The excel has commends already (written by xlsxwriter). The goal is to create a shortcut to toggle individual commends visible/hidden while working with the file.

Comment: Sorry, I did misunderstand. I read "it is feasible" for "is it feasible". BTW, you don't have to store a macro in the file it runs on. You could store it in personal.xlsb so that it is always available.

Comment: Ohh, that sounds good - how do I create this "personal.xlsb" ?

Comment: It should be installed/available by default. In Excel go to "View -> Window -> Unhide" and you should see a hidden workbook called 'PERSONAL.XLSB'. If not google it to see why you don't/how to create one. Then put your macro in the VBA project associated with it and hide it again. It should also be possible to record to it directly without unhiding it by selecting "Personal Macro Workbook" when recording your macro.